# Powershell Webjob fails to run

Tags: powershell, azure-webjobs

I have created a Powershell Webjob for use in the Azure Logic App. The code is trying to generate a signed URI so the end user can download the file when its available. To do that I created a simple Powershell Webjob.

```
New-AzureStorageContext : The term 'New-AzureStorageContext' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. 
CommandNotFoundException New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken : The term 'New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I know these are part of the Azure Powershell. But is there an alternative for them to run? Or would I need to resolve to a separate console application?

Comment: And if i include the Azure powershell module. I run into this error  'Please connect to internet before executing'

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of google searching, I found that Azure Powershell jobs do not support Azure commands. They have a plan to allow for that, but currently you cannot run Azure PowerShell Jobs on WebApps Webjob.

Comment: Please refer this link [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nicktrog/archive/2014/01/22/running-powershell-web-jobs-on-azure-websites.aspx], it is working example of this

Comment: the powershell works file, it is the azure commands that dont work.